# Split a text by word length in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text as below:-

```py
text = "I have an Apple. I have a Banana. I have an Orange. I have a Watermelon."
```

I want to split it into a new pandas dataframe for every 5th word as below:-

| id | Text |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | I have an Apple. I |
| 1 | have a Banana. I have |
| 2 | an Orange I have a |
| 3 | Watermelon |

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What code/approach have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work:

```
text = "I have an Apple. I have a Banana. I have an Orange. I have a Watermelon."
words = text.split()
sentences = []
for i in range(0, len(words), 5):
    sentence = words[i:i+5]
    sentence = ' '.join(sentence)
    sentences.append(sentence)
series = pd.Series(sentences)
df = series.to_frame()
df.columns = ['Text']
```

Then the resulting dataframe `df` would look like this, which is what you have specified in your question:

```
                    Text
0     I have an Apple. I
1  have a Banana. I have
2    an Orange. I have a
3            Watermelon.
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try groupby then aggretate

```py
import pandas as pd

text = "I have an Apple. I have a Banana. I have an Orange. I have a Watermelon."

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': text.split()})

out = df.groupby(df.index//5).agg({'Text': ' '.join})
```

```
print(out)

                    Text
0     I have an Apple. I
1  have a Banana. I have
2    an Orange. I have a
3            Watermelon.
```